# image floating in Underscores doesn't work

Tags: css, wordpress, underscores-wp

I'm using Underscores to build a Wordpress theme.
In the structure I have a div with 275px of width . Inside this div I have another div with `<img>` and `<h3>` inside it. When I try to float the image so the h3 wraps around it the floating doesn't work with the theme but it's working in a separate html file. What's wrong with this code?

```
    .container{
            width: 275px;
        }
        .post-image-small {
            float: left;
        }
        .post-image-small img {
            display: block;
         box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #777;
         box-sizing: border-box;
         border: 1px solid #fff;
         float: left;
       }
        .post-image-small h3.post-title-small {
         font-size: .85em;
         margin: 0 !important;
       }
        .post-image-small h3.post-title-small a {
         color: #444;
         text-decoration: none;
       }
        .post-image-small h3.post-title-small a:hover {
         color: orange;
       }
    <div class="container">
        <div class="post-image-small">
            <img src="http://localhost/viewport/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/iwatsh-150x150.jpg" width="50" height="50">
            <h3 class="post-title-small"><a href="http://localhost/viewport/?p=1490">Integer non nibh et nibh lacinia tempus</a></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What exactly do you mean by using Underscores to build a Wordpress theme?

Comment: Underscores in a starter Wordpress theme and I'm using it to build a new theme

Comment: If you add `!important` after the `float: left;` in `.post-image-small img`, would that work?

Comment: Seems fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/t4265wh7/

Comment: First, Thank you. I mentioned that it works outside the wordpress theme and I wonder if is there any additional Underscores theme styling I didn't catch

Comment: We would need to see all the css since that code should work. The only thing I can think of atm is that the `float` is being specified someone where. So adding `!important` might work.

Comment: @Howlin no it doesn't I've tried it before

Comment: It's really such a small problem but it's really strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In lines 158 to 163 of style.css in **_s** you have this:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    clear: both;}
```

So you need to add this AFTER all the default _S style definistions:

```
.container h3{clear:right}
```

Comment: Thank You. It works.. I've been working with it for about 2 hours.